# Syntax error in nodejs with mysql near to '?'

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

i try to get my hand on database mysql and nodejs. During learning i encounter syntax error on the script and i have no idea how to fix the syntax.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db=require('../database');
router.get('/form', function(req, res, next) { 
res.render('users'); 
});
router.post('/create', function(req, res, next) {

// store all the user input data
const userDetails=req.body;

// insert user data into users table
var sql = 'INSERT INTO users SET ?';
db.query(sql, userDetails,function (err, data) { 
  if (err) throw err;
     console.log("User dat is inserted successfully "); 
});
res.redirect('/users/form');  // redirect to user form page after inserting the data
}); 
module.exports = router;
```

here is the error:

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
errno: 1064,
sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1",
sqlState: '42000',
index: 0,
sql: 'INSERT INTO users SET ?'
```

for reference:
i learn this code from [link](https://www.tutsmake.com/node-js-fetch-and-display-data-from-mysql-database-in-html-list/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Amadan, so in my case, I have 5 column in users table. How should i write the syntax? the column consist of id,fullName, emailAddress, city, and country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what the specific implementation of the `db.query` function is, but you probably want something like this (I got the db schema from your other comment):

```
let sql = 'INSERT INTO users SET id=?, fullName=?, emailAddress=?, city=?, country=?';
db.query(sql, userDetails, function (err, data) { 
  if (err) {
     throw err;
  }
  console.log("User dat is inserted successfully "); 
});
```

If that doesn't work try setting the SQL variable to this instead:

```
let sql = 'INSERT INTO users (id, fullName, emailAddress, city, country) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
```

I'm assuming  that `userDetails` variable references an object with the following type: `{ id, fullName, emailAddress, city, country }`.

SQL requires a question mark for each column on each insertion when using prepared statements. The `db.query` function might be trying to insert the object directly as a string, which could cause an issue because your schema has 5 columns. The JSON syntax of the `stringified` object might also cause the SQL parser to complain.

If that doesn't work, I'd like to look at your schema. Your function seems to send the `req.body` object to the database directly, which would mean the user is sending the id directly to the database. This is rather uncommon, usually the id of a row is generated by the server or an autoincrement column in the database.

I hope this works out for you, feel free to respond if you have any questions or concerns.

Answer (score 0):

you can't pass the data like {field1 : 1, field2 : 2, field3 : 3}.
pass this 'INSERT INTO users SET field1 = ?, field2 = ?';

```
const userDetails=[
                    1, // this value is field1
                    2, // this value is field2
                  ];

// insert user data into users table
var sql = 'INSERT INTO users SET field1 = ?, field2 = ?';
db.query(sql, userDetails,function (err, data) { 
  if (err) throw err;
     console.log("User dat is inserted successfully "); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We assume the values are objects:

```js
userDetails = {
  name: "Rum Haidar F.",
  dob: "1990-01-01",
  address: "Foo Bar Street"
}
```

Try to add [ values ]:

```js
// insert
var sql = 'INSERT INTO users SET ?';
db.query(sql, [userDetails], function (err, data) { 
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("User dat is inserted successfully "); 
});
```

For UPDATE data [ values, YOUR CONDITION ]:

```js
// update
var sql = 'UPDATE users SET ? WHERE user_id = ? AND status = ?';
db.query(sql, [userDetails, 69, 'active'],function (err, data) { 
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("User dat is inserted successfully "); 
});
```